# ASPxListBox EnableSelectAll is defined as not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Sorry for my bad english
Anyway, I have a problem with adding EnableSelectAll to my ASPxListBox, my List Box isn't have select all as default property.

i've google it and many says that i just have to add EnableSelectAll="true". when i do it, nothing happen to my listbox. so i decided to enable it when im uploading a file but when i do then, like all the title says, Chrome's console says EnableSelectAll is not a function.

This is the ASPx Code

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="FileContainer" ClientInstanceName="FileContainer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100" ClientVisible="false" SelectionMode="CheckColumn" EnableSelectAll="True"/>
```

and this is the JavaScript code

```
function onFileUploadComplete(s, e) 
{
FileContainer.EnableSelectAll(true);
}
```

The result would be like:

Uncaught TypeError: FileContainer.EnableSelectAll is not a function

at onFileUploadComplete (Complaint.aspx?treeid=0101100000001:102)

is there anyone that have the same issue and would you please guide me how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Did you debug it? Make  sure the result not showing null for FileContainer at line FileContainer.EnableSelectAll(true)?

Comment: Yes i have, FileContainer has one file at a time onFileUploadComplete executed

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, because [there is no *function* named `EnableSelectAll`](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/11627/asp.net-webforms-controls/data-editors/aspxlistbox/aspxlistbox-overview) in the `ASPxListBox` control. [`ASPxListBox.EnableSelectAll` is a property](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxListBox.EnableSelectAll).

You need to do this instead:

```
FileContainer.EnableSelectAll = true
```

Also, I don't know if this is case sentitive or not, but you might want to change:

```
EnableSelectAll="True"
```

to:

```
EnableSelectAll="true"
```

Comment: then what do i EnableSelectAll if i didn't call the FileContainer?

Comment: @adam_hdt : I don't understand what you mean, please try to clarify.